# COMMAND_FAILED error when trying to add services to firewalld

Tags: centos, firewalld

I'm trying to add ftp service to firewalld, and every time I run `firewall-cmd --add-service=ftp` (this is with out the permanent flag) I get `Error: COMMAND_FAILED`.
If I run `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp` (this is with the permanent flag), it returns `success`.

However after I reload the service I can't connect via ssh until I disable firewalld over rescue mode.

I'm not trying to open ssh's port. I'm just stating that I lose access to the server after running `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp` and then reload with `firewall-cmd --reload`.

Comment: What makes you think `--add-service=ftp` for port `21` would open port `22` used by SSH?

Comment: that's not at all what im trying to do, im saying after i run firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp and reload firewalld   i get locked out of ssh

Comment: and if i run the command without the --permanent flag i get Error: COMMAND_FAILED any time i try to add a service to firewalld  i was using ftp as an example

Answer (score -1):

Indeed this happens with grs kernel on Centos 7. Actually, your question includes the answer. In order to eliminate the problem you need to avoid using the command `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ftp` when opening firewalld ports, or remove it if it is already there with `firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ftp`. This solves the issue!

You can use the command `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=21/tcp` though, so you can have port 21 open if you want.

The explanation is that firewalld tries to load the **nf_conntrack_ftp** kernel module, even when module support is disabled, and in grs kernel this module is disabled indeed.

I can guess that even if you don't use a grs kernel, you have the **nf_conntrack_ftp** kernel module disabled. If you reverse this reasoning, you could enable this module, but I am not sure if you can, and I have not tried this solution that looks obvious to me.

This also solves the problem of being locked out after `firewall-cmd --reload` when service=ftp is added in firewalld, which in fact is the problem I had with the grs kernel.